# Close and reopen tag around specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to close a `<span>` tag before the word "hello" and reopen it just after when a button is clicked.

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8Ra9L/)**

This is my code :

```
<span class="border"> 
    border Hello border border
</span>
<div> 
    <span class="button">Style me !</span>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.border').each(function () {
        var t = $(this).text();
        var s = t.split('Hello').join('</span>Hello<span class="border">');
        $(this).html(s)
    });
});
```

The HTML output I have after clicking `.button` is :

```
<span class="border"> 
    border Hello<span class="border"> border border
</span>
```

And the output I want is :

```
<span class="border"> 
    border </span>Hello<span class="border"> border border
</span>
```

**Why isn't the `.join` function inserting the `</span>` closing tag?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify the dom structure like a string, but you'd have to target the parent element as you can't insert partial elements

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.border').each(function () {
        var t = $(this).parent().html();
        var s = t.split('Hello').join('</span>Hello<span class="border">');
        $(this).parent().html(s)
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8Ra9L/3/)

Note that this works with the example, but if the parent has other elements as well, it can cause issues, and I would strongly suggest finding another way to get the result you're looking for other than closing and opening elements in the middle etc.

***EDIT:***

Here's another way of doing it, this doesn't affect the parent at all, and is much neater.
It uses `outerHTML` to get the surrounding tags as well, that way no partial elements are inserted, but both opening and closing tags are part of the strings passed

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.border').each(function () {
        this.outerHTML = this.outerHTML.split('Hello').join('</span>Hello<span class="border">');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8Ra9L/4/)

or the even neater jQuery version

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.border').prop('outerHTML', function(_, html) {
        return html.split('Hello').join('</span>Hello<span class="border">');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8Ra9L/9/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you evil genius on his way to conquer the universe!

Comment: @web-tiki - Excellent !

Comment: one last issue, lets say there are several strings that need the closing/opening tags ("Hello, meeToo, thisToo") would there be a neater way than repeating the function several times? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8Ra9L/16/

Comment: I will vote for you if you ever try to be president of the universe although you won't, evil genius conquers!

Comment: @web-tiki - Thanks, I'll just adopt the title "supreme ruler".

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the dom structure like a string.

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.border').replaceWith(function () {
        var parts = $(this).text().split('Hello');
        return '<span class="border">' + parts.join('</span>Hello<span class="border">') + '</span>';
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nZF3t/)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "Hello" word with your string you want

```
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('.border').each(function () {
            var t = $(this).text();
            var s = t.replace('Hello', '</span>Hello<span class="border">');
            $(this).html(s)
        });
    });
```